# Check if value already is in list property

Tags: c#, list

Below I am trying to see if the text is already contained in the list. The code always goes into the if statement.Why?

```
if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.FindAll(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName ) != null)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use Any instead of FindAll

```
if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName ))
```

`FindAll` doesn't return  null if value is not found, it returns an empty collection.

So you could do (but don't)

```
 if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.FindAll(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName ).Any())
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName))
{
    ...
}
```

or [List.Exists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx)

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Exists(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName))
{
    ...
}
```