# Check if List value matches a list value in another list

Tags: c#, list

I have 2 lists - I need to see if a value in one list property exists in a list property of a second list.I tried the code below but it does not compile.
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'" - I think i should be using 'contains' but im not 100%

```
if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(x => x.sItemName == MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Any(y => y.sItemName))) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if value already is in list property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511565/check-if-value-already-is-in-list-property)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any
     (x => MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Any(y => y.sItemName == x.sItemName))) 
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative

```
if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Join(
    MyGlobals.lstNewItems, 
    x => x.sItemName, 
    y => y.sItemName, 
    (x, y) => x).Any()) 
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Intersect`?

```
if(MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Select(x => x.sItemName)
    .Intersect(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Select(y => y.sItemName)).Any())
{
    // ...
}
```

You can also supply an `IEqualityComparer` to perform whatever comparison between your objects which would probably make this code neater - especially if there is more than a simple string comparison.